# QGIS: graphical-modeler to calculate area of polygons

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, area

I'm trying to calculate the area of polygons using the field-calculator in QGIS (2.0.1). If I do this manualy it works fine, but if I do this using the graphical-modeler I get NULL as area for every Polygon. I just typet `$area` in the Formula field. Field-type is integer and length is 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Field Calculator is not working within the modeller, but the Advanced Python Field Calculator is doing the job: `value = $geom.area()`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the `Field Calculator` within the Graphical Modeler, if one makes use of the input **vector field**. Consider a vector layer, that is the output of a `dissolve` and `multipart to singleparts` operation, resulting in wrong values of `Shape_Area`:

[image: input vector layer table view]

Here, it is called `Layer_for_calculating_area`, and the field to be recalculated is `Shape_Area`.

| 1. Define an input for the **vector layer**: | 2. Define an input for the **vector field**: |
| --- | --- |
| [image: input vector layer] | [image: input vector field] |

3. In the algorithm window for Field Calculator, choose “**using model input**” for both input layer and field name, and don't forget to set the desired output field length and the precision. Formula: `$area` (see the [QGIS documentation 24.5.2.2.](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html#definition-of-the-workflow)):

[image: algorithm field calculator]

4. After hitting the button run model (or key F5), [image: Button run model]

make sure that the dropdown lists show the correct inputs, respectively.

[image: graphical model]

After the model has created the output layer, a manual measurement shows that the values of the field Shape_Area are now correct:

[image: test manual measurement]

Comment: Hej! Thank you SO SO SO much, I just missed a part in your step 4! where is the button run model, where do you find the parameters?

Comment: Glad that the answer is helpful for you. I edited the step 4 to make it clear.